# How to use NumberExpression returned by SQLExpression.datediff() in querydsl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datediff, querydsl

I am doing self-join on a table and using  SQLExpression.datediff like so:

```
QSomeTable tb1 = new QSomeTable("tb1");
QSomeTable tb2 = new QSomeTable("tb2");
NumberExpression<Integer> ne  = SQLExpression.datediff(DatePart.hour, tb1.time,     tb2.time);


query.from(tb1, tb2).where........list(ne);
```

This gives the following exception:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode

I tried selecting some other fields in the list clause and it works without problems.

Highly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLExpressions are not supported in Querydsl JPA queries, since they are not supported by JPQL. They are also difficult to emulate since the serialization of these expressions is SQL dialect specific.

Comment: I am trying to user QueryDSL sql to calculate the datediff. I tried the 3.3.2 version, but the SQLQUeryImpl class is missing from this version. I then tried a previous 2.9.0 version. This one has SQLQueryImpl but the datediff method is missing from the SQLExpressions class. Could you please point me to the right querydsl sql version?

Comment: SQLQueryImpl changed to SQLQuery.

Answer (score 1):

So my work around for this problem was to create a view and then use a Spring entity to map the view. Querydsl works seamlessly on top of this entity.

In my case, I did something like this:

View in DB:

create view my_view as select t.id as id, timestampdiff(SECOND,t.time1,t.time2) as timediff from my_table t;

Spring entity

```
@Entity(name="my_view")
public class MyTableBean{

@Id 
@Column(name="id")
Long id;

@Column(name="timediff")
Long timediff;

//Getters and setters

}
```

Now any query can be written for this view like a normal table

```
 QMyTableBean qt = new QMyTableBean();
 // Initilize entity manager and JPQL query

 Long res = query.from(qt).where.....list(qt.timediff);
```

This has the advantage of making the code dialect independent.
Views are supported by all major SQL stores and if a migration happens in the future, impact on application is minimal.